# Javascript- settimeout using boolean

Tags: javascript, boolean, settimeout

What I want to accomplish is this:

```
while(!bool){
    // do nothing, just wait until bool is true
}
// now go do subsequent code
```

in Javascript, and not using a while loop since it freezes all the other code. However, setTimeout seems dependent on being given an actual time value. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: It sounds like its freezing due to an infinite loop. What are you trying to evaluate as true?

Comment: I have a callback listening for UDP packets that will set the boolean value as true at a certain point. However, if I understand correctly, trying to set a timeout in Javascript using a while loop will freeze my other Javascript code, so that callback won't be triggered while the while loop runs.

Answer (score 4):

Keep calling `setTimeout` until the condition is true.

```
function doSubsequentCode() {
    // now go do subsequent code
}

function testForCondition() {
    if (bool) {
        doSubsequentCode();
    } else {
        setTimeout(testForCondition, 1000);
    }
}

testForCondition();
```

---

From your comments on the question:

> I have a callback listening for UDP packets that will set the boolean value as true at a certain point.

Don't use `setTimeout` at all. Don't use `bool` at all. Just put `doSubsequentCode();` in the callback function. That is what callbacks are for.

Comment: I apologize- it seems my intent in my original question wasn't sufficiently clear. What I'm trying to do isn't really a standard callback sort of thing. I'm trying to create a sort of "handshake" between two callbacks that seem to be executing on separate threads, and thought there might be a quick and dirty solution that wouldn't require elaborating. I'm not sure now whether I should edit the question or start a new one entirely.